# Convert string to NSDictionary, JSON, or NSArray

Tags: objective-c

A web service that I query returns the following string:

```
LoginCaregiverPortalResult =     {
        "a:Agencies" =         {
            "b:KeyValueOfintHealthAgencyk3OpkD63" =             {
                "b:Key" = 1;                    
                "b:Value" = "true56246845405624684545falsefalse12falsefalse13";
            };
        };
        "a:Error" = "";
        "a:HasError" = false;
        "a:Token" = "gIyAGKITTVNZf9i8xLJ6ADZcJhSnFkxv1Mx4y1DOsd";
    };
}
```

Is there a generic way, without having to write a custom parser to convert this string to either NSDictionary, NSJSONSerialization, or NSArray? Different queries will return different keys/values so writing individual code for each case would be too cumbersome.

Also, I am using XCode 6.1.

Comment: It looks to me like the above is a dump of an NSDictionary from parsed JSON.  (You're missing the leading `{`, but it's "normal" for someone to omit that because they don't realize it's significant.)  I suggest you query the type of the actual received value and see if it's not an NSDictionary.

Comment: @HotLicks: You are correct. I used something like `NSString *className = [[obj class] description]` to determine that it was indeed a NSDictionary.  Thanks!